# How to reduce text size in a tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a program in tkinter and I would like to reduce the text size and the only thing I can do is reduce the size of the button. I cut less important code.
This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
label1 = Label(okno, text="Kto wybił klan Uchiha?", font=30 )
label1.config(font=(30, 43, 'bold'))
label1.pack()
okno: Tk = Tk()
okno.geometry('700x850')
okno.title('Poziom Łatwy')
okno.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying the font correctly in your code. There are several ways to do it — here's some [documentation](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/fonts.html).

Using the way that consists of using a `tuple` containing the *`<font family>`*, *`<size>`*, and optionally a string of one or more *`<style modifiers>`* in your code would make it look something like what's below.

Note that I extracted the font family name from the `'TkDefaultFont'` because I didn't want that to change. (Thanks to @Bryan Oakley for explaining to me the way to do that.)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter.font as tkfont

okno: Tk = Tk()
okno.geometry('700x850')
okno.title('Poziom Łatwy')

default_font_family = tkfont.nametofont('TkDefaultFont').cget('family')

label1 = Label(okno, text="Kto wybił klan Uchiha?", font=(default_font_family, 30))
label1.config(font=(default_font_family, 20, 'bold'))
label1.pack()

okno.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using the font face `TkDefaultFont` isn't quite doing what you think it's doing. You could just as well use "BogusFont".  The end result is the same in either case: tkinter sees an unrecognized font family and substitutes the default font. "TkDefaultFont" is the internal name of a font object, which isn't the same as a font family.

Comment: @Bryan: OK, so what would you recommend using when one wants the default font?

Comment: There are a couple ways. You can either clone the default font and then change the size on the cloned font, or you can get the family of the default font with something like `tkinter.font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont").cget("family")`

Comment: @Bryan; Thanks — modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: You can give an example of how to make the text smaller, because how to change the numerical values ​​of the numbers in your answer, the only thing that gets  is the reduction of the button itself

Comment: Norbrakor: I don't understand your comment. The code reduces the size of the text on the button — which I thought was what you asked how to do. If not, you need to clarify your question (by editing the question, not by explaining down here with a comment).